# ASP.NET validators alignment issue

Tags: asp.net, validation

I am developing contactus webpage which have a input field called Email. It is validated against a required field validator and regular expression validator with appropriate messages.

Required: Enter Email
Regular Expression: Invalid Email

I am setting these two as given below:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <font color="#FF0000">*</font>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvemail" CssClass="error_text" ControlToValidate="txtEmail"
                                        runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter email address."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                         <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revemail" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail"
                                            ErrorMessage="Invalid Email" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

My problem is both Enter Email and Invalid Email is occupying its own space. For Ex: If I leave email as empty space and press submit, Enter Email is displaying right next to it. If I enter invalid email(xxx), Enter Email is off but taking the space, Invalid Email message is displayed after these space taken by 'Enter Email' before.

Is there any way to remove this space??

Mahesh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set Display = "Dynamic" on it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.display%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. My RequiredFieldValidator and RegularExpressionValidator were causing the regex message to shift right. Here is my corrected code:

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email"
 Display="Dynamic" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The email field is required." />

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email"
 CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid email address formatted as (name@domain.com)" Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$" />

Answer (score 5):

Use `Diplay = "Dynamic"`

**The display behavior for the validation control. Legal values are:**

- None (the control is not displayed. Used to show the error message only in the 
  ValidationSummary control)
- Static (the control displays an error message if validation fails. Space is 
  reserved on the page for the message even if the input passes validation.
- Dynamic (the control displays an error message if validation fails. Space is not 
  reserved on the page for the message if the input passes validation

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question correctly, I think the answer is to set the `Display` property to `Dynamic`.

If you're using ASP.NET Themes, you can set this as the default for all validators in your Theme using a Skin file, so you never have to worry about it again.